# 9,1 iMac GPU upgrade

Tags: imac, gpu

I replaced the NVIDIA 130GT w/ a 4850 AMD Radeon card from a 27" imac, same year (late 2009).  Computer boots, all 4 LEDs go on, computer accessible from remote screensharing on the LAN so is obviously up and running.  No picture on the screen (backlighting working).

I think it's an EFI/firmware problem w/ the new card. Any ideas as to a work-around?  Edit the BIOS in the GPU to match the 24 inch screen or the Logic board ID?  Thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: does it start up in Safe mode or Single user mode?

Answer (score 1):

It starts fine, but no image on the screen. Clearly think it's a GPU-CPU issue, but obviously they are talking or all 4 LED's wouldn't light up....so it must be something written into the EFI that's preventing screen imaging, I'm thinking.

Comment: You should comment instead of post an answer